# Extracting Array from Object

Tags: java, arrays, object, casting

How can I extract the elements of an array of objects of type A from an Object reference o?

```
A a_1 = new A();
A a_2 = new A();
A a_3 = new A();
Object o = new A[] {a_1, a_2, a_3};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `o` is an `Object` that you need to cast to `A[]` 
and then you can use the result of this type cast as an array of `A` objects:

```
A a = ((A[]) o)[0];
```